# qqPlot with Two Outliers

Tags: r, normal-distribution, outliers, qq-plot

If I have a QQ plot with two extreme outliers (picture below) how should I interpret it? Do I drop the outliers? Can I treat it as normal?[image]

Comment: What you have aren't outliers (at least probably, I suppose we'll never know), you have a right-skewed distribution.

Comment: There is nothing in a Q-Q plot to tell you whether any point is an outlier or not ... don't use Q-Q plots for detecting outliers.

Comment: They don't appear to be outliers to me (and certainly not extreme ones), but even if you removed those points, your underlying issue (skewness relative to the theoretical distribution in your plot) would remain, and you'd simply have biased your inference. Failing to solve the problem but making the inference biased doesn't seem like a great tradeoff to me.

Comment: To spell it out, the main pattern here is curvature, indicating a distribution that is positively skewed. The two highest points are broadly consistent with that.